# Angular application deployment in elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my backend java springboot application to EBS and now I am trying to deploy my angular application to EBS but is not getting deployed successfully.
I created EBS of type node and I tried deployed in 2 ways:

1. using awsebcli with bellow commands:

> eb init, ng build --configuration=production, eb deploy

2. using aws console
   created build by running: ng build --configuration=production
   and then zipped dist folder and deployed

Nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

1- Create application with the same vpc of your springBoot Application

2- Choose Tomcat and not Node

3- Build your project & Zip the www

4- Deploy the archive